# Mahapps Metro IDialogCoordinator.ShowMetroDialogAsync Execution Order

Tags: mvvm, mahapps.metro

My goal is to make two successive calls to ShowMetroDialogAsync to display a custom input dialog box followed by a custom message box.

First this call

```
_dialogCoordinator.ShowMetroDialogAsync(this, _inputDialogView);
```

followed by

```
_dialogCoordinator.ShowMetroDialogAsync(this, _messageDialogView);
```

However instead of the input dialog getting shown first, the message dialog gets shown and the order seems random when I execute the Command consecutively, i.e. sometimes the input dialog gets displayed followed by the message dialog and vice versa.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: They're async, so you must await the first call before making the second call.  Or use [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) to schedule the second call after the first has completed.  If you're going to be using async methods, you should spend some time to learn how they work.

Comment: I have tried await, similar results.

Comment: "Or use Task.ContinueWith to schedule the second call after the first has completed."